# Call Partial view/Child page in Master layout using jQuery / Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, layout

I'm working on a CRM Admin panel, where I'm using the left-hand side panel to navigate to other pages. There are multiple buttons like Home, About, Contact, etc.

I created a master layout and added views, and set the view links on those buttons. When I click on one of the buttons, the whole page does load. I want to load the child page without refreshing the entire page/master layout. I have to need to use partial pages. but I don't know how can I call that partial pages using the button click or label clicks. Or is there any better idea for achieving this??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cDwb.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding ajax function to the button click event.

**Button in Main View**

```
<button onclick="loadPartialView()">Click me</button>
```

This ajax function will bind the partial view to an ID in the main view.

**Ajax function**

```
function loadPartialView() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Controller/PartialViewReturningActionMethod",
        success: function (result, status) {
            $("#IdInMainView").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller code**

```
public ActionResult PartialViewReturningActionMethod()
{
      return PartialView(//pathOfPartialView , data)
}
```

In main view you should have an empty div like this

```
<div id="IdInMainView">
</div>
```

Also you must add script references to jQuery.